# JHipster registry, change properties value in spring cloud config server

Tags: java, spring, jhipster, microservices, spring-cloud

I'm trying to migrate from monolithic web application to microservices.
For doing this I'm using JHipster v 4.11.1 (very helpful!).

My problem is:
In JHipster registry (central-config folder) I wrote some  property files and every microservice, on startup, read the owned properties.
I need to change this properties on runtime both from registry and from every microservices.

There are any ways to do this? I have to use kafka or somethings like that?

JHipster Registry is a Spring Cloud Config server and should allow this behavior but I'm new with this stuff and  maybe I lost some information. For now I don't use Git or SVN repository, but only a native configuration.

Comment: You must call the refresh endpoint of your service (/management/refresh in JHipster) to make it reload its application properties. See https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Finchley.M5/single/spring-cloud.html#_environment_changes

Comment: If I call the refresh endpoint I can only reload the properties.
I need to change the properties both from registry and from a web interface outside the registry. Every service can change some properties and new instance of that service must be started with that new value..

Furthermore, If i change the properties in central-config/service1.yml in registry, how can advise every instance of service1?

Comment: I haven't checked the features of the registry recently, so maybe this feature  does already exist but if it does not it should be easy to add it and you could contribute it

Comment: Config Server does not have an interface for modifying properties. Config Monitor is the way to notify clients of changes http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Edgware.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud.html#_push_notifications_and_spring_cloud_bus

Comment: Ok, so I can notify every instance of service1 throwing RefreshRemoteApplicationEvent and using the spring-cloud-bus. right?

"Config Server does not have an interface for modifying properties." There are any infrastructure or pattern reasons for this?